# $S^1$ is the only compact connected 1-manifold (without boundary).

Tags: general-topology

Here '**1-manifold**' is just a Hausdorff space which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^1$. (It is not necessasrily connected or second countable.)

I am sorry, I know that this is a kind of duplicate question. There are a lot of questions about classification of 1-manifolds, but I find the answers on them too hard to understand. The thing is, I don't need the full result of classification of 1-manifolds, and 1-manifolds with boundaries are out of my consideration. I just want to show that $S^1$ is the only possible compact connected 1-manifold without boundary, using elementary facts in topology. Hopefully these restrictions make the problem substantially simpler..? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You still need connected, otherwise any finite disjoint union of circles is still a 1-manifold under your definition.

Comment: In fact, a compact Hausdorff space is necessarily second countable.